# C printf() on win32 with mingw

Tags: windows, printf, mingw, sdl-2

I develop an SDL2 application for fun on Linux, however I do Windows builds as well for non-Linux users even without testing it (I have no Windows at all, never had). I use mingw for that, cross compilation. Everything works nicely but one thing. The application has some command line switches/messages/help as well using simple printf() in C. However that simply does not work on Windows, no output is shown, according to the users. I found this: `setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` but it didn't helped. Also, I found `-mwindows` switch of mingw in various documents and `-mconsole` but since I don't know Windows well, I have no idea how things should work on this strange to me system (Windows). Basically I would like similar solution as with Linux: if you start from a terminal window, you can see the stdout, but if not, they can't be seen at all, no window is open/shown for those messages etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of no windows alternative with the same behaviour as linux programs.

Without `-mwindows` (aside from many other things), your output will be directed to stdout and displayed in cmd (and can be routed to other processes stdin via pipes), but if you'll run it without cmd - it will open an extra console window for output.

With `-mwindows` stdio no longer linked to console. You still can redirect output, but you don't see it (so e.g. `your_program.exe | cat` will display output, but there is no `cat` in standard windows). This mode however doesn't autoopen console window. You can create console manually (or inherit parent process's console) and redirect stdout to it (with `freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout)`), but this wouldn't be 'true' stdio and you can't pipe it to other processes (which may still be fine for you).

Comment: I see, and thanks. Without -mwindows will new console open automatically or only at the first output? Can I test somehow that I already have a console or new _would_ open? Is stdio buffered? I guess if did printf()'s and only then did freopen() trick, the old messages are lost, right (I mean with -mwindows)? In general, it is possible to control the cmd window newly opened (and test if already has one) without -mwindows? Ie, closing it, or test if I already has, etc. Sorry for the many possible beginner questions. Thanks!

Comment: Well I'm not windows expert, but most of you said appears to be correct. I think most of the confusion happens because windows fundamentally separates console and windows applications. For console application console window appears even before your `main` and automatically closes once your program quits. For windows application, you either manually `AllocConsole` or `AttachConsole(-1)` to attach to parent's process console, or ever make a command line switch to optionally do so; then you reattach stdin/stdout/stderr and disable buffering if you need to.

Comment: Thanks again! For me, you are a windows expert especially compared to myself :) I will look after those suggested functions.